# Implementation of Cepstrum in Python

Tags: fft, python, ifft, denoising, software-implementation

Actually I want to denoise a signal. I know how can I implement FFT in python to denoise it. This is the implementation which I use(From [this](https://www.kaggle.com/theoviel/fast-fourier-transform-denoising) Kaggle notebook):
[image]

But I don't know :

1. How can I use cepstrum like FFT to denoise signal?
2. Are there any implementations in python like FFT code?

Comment: Have you had a look at the references of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum). The original paper is there along with a few others that provide a comprehensive view of the cepstrum and how to use it?

Comment: No, Thanks a lot, In your opinion which references are better for it?

Comment: Definitely 1 so you can see what the original authors were dealing with and how did they go about solving it. From there, the first and the last of the "Further Reading" section are very illuminating about the Cepstrum. In the meantime, you might find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68521/generating-spectrum-of-a-spectrum-identifying-frequencies-of-ripples-present-i/68579#68579) helpful too.